# change document root with .htaccess internal redirect not working properly

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

Hello my fellow developers,
i need to change my document root some specific folder which holds the source code of my laravel project on a shared hosting, since my hosting plan dont let me change default document root so i cannot change my default index so i want to have to redirect it using `.htaccess`

for far i have been able to internally redirect with the following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ master/project/public/index.php
```

doing this i am able to redirect to desired folder, but for some reason it is not working for assets, i keep getting `404` on all the assets

```
master/project/public/css/[all styles]
master/project/public/js/[all scritps]
master/project/public/images/[all pictures]
master/project/public/fonts/[all fonts]
```

how can i achieve this without having to change urls,

internal redirect is working but i cannot figure out why all of my assets are returning 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i found solution to my problem,
this solution is what i ended up with.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !master/project/public/
RewriteRule (.*) /master/project/public/$1 [L]
```

this way you can change the default root of the your hosting using `.htaccess` file. hopefully it is helpful for everybody new to .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Try this
i m using shared hosting and this i m using for redirect asset to public dir

```sh
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    #all request to public dir
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

To redirect all request to public

```sh
 #all request to public dir
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```